# Difficult Inverse trigo problem

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, trigonometric-series, inverse-function

Given
$$\arccos(y_1) + \arccos(y_2) + \dots + \arccos(y_k) =kπ$$
for any value of $k>1$ and 
$$
A= y_1^1 + y_2^2 + \dots + y_{2k}^{2k},
$$
the task is to find the value of $A$.

I have no idea from where should I start with the problem. I tried taking cosine on both sides in first equation but it's not helping.

Comment: please use latex to format your text

Comment: The maximum value achieved by the arc cosine is $\pi$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\arccos(y_k)=\sum_{i=1}^k \arccos(y_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\arccos(y_i)=k\pi-(k-1)\pi=\pi$$
$$y_k=-1$$
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^{2k}(-1)^i=0$$